# dojo dialog background (frame border, close button, etc) not appears

Tags: dojo, modal-dialog

I am facing strange problem with dojo, I am not able to get background of dojo dialog( frame border, close button, etc,.)

I am only getting Title string and Content string, I can able to move the title string along with content string as like dialog, so I confirmed dialog popup is done, but not able to get background things of dialog.

I am using "claro" theme, I am also displaying "Button", it is coming nice with "claro" theme, but dialog is not coming, please help to find out the problem.

Note: I am running dojo from my own server.

Comment: Is it possible that your button is inside a div with `class="claro"`, while the Dialog is placed somewhere outside this div? Do you have `class="claro"` on your body tag?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?  It is hard to understand what exactly you're seeing on screen here.

Answer (score 1):

You need two things.

1) 
You **must** embed the Claro CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/your/dojo/copy/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
```

2)
You **must** add the class **claro** to your **body** tag.

```
<body class="claro">
</body>
```